# Searching through data stored in Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, bigdata, full-text-search, azure-data-lake, data-lake

I have the following use case for building a Data Lake (e.g. in Azure):

My organization deals with companies that go into bankruptcy. Once a company goes bankrupt, it needs to hand over all of their data to us, including structured data (e.g. CSVs) as well as semi-structured and unstructured data (e.g. PDFs, Word documents, images, JSON, .txt files etc.). Having a data lake would help here as the volumes of data can be large and unpredictable and Azure Data Lake seems like a relatively low-cost and scalable storage solution.

However, apart from storing all of that data we also need to give business users a tool that will enable them to search through all of that data. I can imagine two search types:

- searching for specific files (using file names or part of file names as the search criteria)
- searching through all text files (word documents, .txt and PDFs) and identifying those files that meet the search criteria (e.g. a specific phrase being searched for)

Are there any out of the box tools that can use Azure Data Lake as a data source that would enable users to perform such searches?

Comment: Hi RobW, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please mark it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a tool can help you filter the files directly in Data Lake for now.

Even [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=windows) only support search by prefix.

[Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) support we filter the files,  but it usually used for copy and transfer data. Reference: [Data Factory supports wildcard file filters for Copy Activity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/data-factory-supports-wildcard-file-filter-for-copy-activity/)

**Update:**

[Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search) seems to be a good choice.

Cognitive Search supports import source from Data Lake, and it provide the filter to help us search the files.

A filter provides criteria for selecting documents used in an Azure Cognitive Search query. Unfiltered search includes all documents in the index. A filter scopes a search query to a subset of documents.

We could reference from [Filters in Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about Azure Cognitive Search?

Comment: @RobW Thanks, I just read the overview of Azure Cognitive Search, it seems a good choice. You could try it. I'm glad that we can learn from each other. I have updated my answer. You can think about mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Cognitive Search with Azure Data Lake Gen 2 is currently in preview, so you can try it out but be a bit wary of using it for production workloads.

Answer (score 0):

Cognitive Search with Azure Data Lake is definitely an option and it is Microsoft recommends. Several factors we need to consider:

1. Price. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/. Not a cheap option.
2. Size of your source data and index you need.
3. Your acknowledgment of other open-source services. ELK is a popular open-source framework for full-text searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of az + grep in bash.
For example, in this request I search for 3 files in any sub dir under path.

```bash
# Search blobs with certain file names
az storage fs file list \
    --account-name=<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME> \
    --file-system=<CONTAINER_NAME> \
    --path="raw/quests/transformed/" \
    --query="[].{name:name}" \
    --exclude-dir \
    --auth-mode=login \
    --output=table \
    | grep 'quest_571.csv\|quest_562.csv\|quest_528.csv'
```